# Difference between rndc and nsupdate

Tags: dns, bind

Im setting up environment for dynamic dns updating and was testing nsupdate, but then again there is rndc tool. What is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nsupdate` is used for composing and sending dynamic updates for DNS records.

`rndc` is used for operational control of a name server.